# Untar a UNIX-based operating system

Tags: unix

I am trying to untar UNIX-based operating system from a .tar.gz file. In order to do so I use the following command:

> tar -xvf rootfs.tar.gz -o

The -o flag is to not to preserve the ownership of the files (it gave some problems). The problem is that when a symbolic link is untared the following  message shows up

> Cannot create symlink to `toto': Operation not permitted

Moreover, mknod also gives problems

> dev/tty0: Cannot mknod: Operation not permitted

I am in a FAT system. Does anyone know how to untar that file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running as root?  Probably not, but you probably need to be.  You're using a FAT (file) system?  Are you running on Windows, expecting to use Unix?  Please clarify what system you are running on.  Can you explain why you expect this to work at all?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was trying to create a USB for a embedded processor that runs on a debian based system. FAT file system was required for that case. And, yes, I was as root. The thing was that FAT does not support symbolic links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is a tar.gz you must use:

```
tar -xvzf rootfs.tar.gz
```

And notice that a FAT filesystem doesn't support symbolic links, so it doesn't know how to make it on that FS, and it explains the Operation Not Permitted Error.

Comment: The `v` is verbose; report the file names as they're extracted.  The `z` is optional with GNU Tar (modern versions); it automatically deduces that files containing gzip-compressed data should be uncompressed first, and likewise for bzip2 data.  You're right about the FAT file system not really supporting symlinks; it probably doesn't support block or character devices (such as `/dev/tty0`) either.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the question was how to skip those "nonfiles" that cause errors.

Comment: yeah i know that -v is for verbose!! but i didn't knew that now tar doesn't need -z option anymore :) (i was still using that option) thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: GNU tar doesn't need `-z` (it can figure from the `.gz`), but non-GNU tar commands might still need it.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work for me. And yes the user unzipping is root.

Answer (score 2):

+1 fpr Ivan's answer

please note that:

flags always go right after the name of the command!

you will need to study "man tar" to see what other options you want, e.g. preserve owner, permissions, time-creation date, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is that if you're trying to untar a UNIX root file system, that's going to include special files such as device nodes (which is why `tar` is invoking `mknod`).

To create those successfully, `tar` must be allowed to run as root. Therefore, the correct answer is to use `sudo`, like so:

```
sudo tar -xvzf rootfs.tar.gz
```

Comment: Someone downvoted this, but the answer is valid. Tar cannot create special files without being executed with root privileges.

Answer (score -4):

Try this to untar a tar file. Hopefully it will work fine without any problem, as this one solved my issue

```
tar -xvvf foo.tar
```

Comment: -1 because you have not explained whether or how this command is different from the one OP gave in the question.